# jquery animate not working in IE-7 and IE-8

Tags: jquery, image, internet-explorer, slider, jquery-animate

I am facing some isssues in IE-8 and IE-7. The jquery animate is not working in IE-7 and IE-8. I giving you my demo server link where I have uploaded all the code. [Demo Server URL](http://indivar.info/testjquery)

Just click on the Our Menu link on the left side. After clicking you see a page with full bg image and small image on from in the box. When I click on the next button both the images changes.

This is working fine in Firefox, Chrome, Safari and IE-9.

But in IE-7 and IE-8, the bg image changes for the very first time. After that it doesn't changed according to the box images in the front.

I am not able to understand what actually is the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an undefined function call `test();` on `line 227` and this may block explorer to execute javascript. Chrome and Firefox may tolerate javascript errors sometimes but explorer rarely tolerates.

***Edit:***

it seems this is a problem from original plugin. I suggest you to ask plugin owner how to fix it or if there is a newer version

or

you can use http://www.jslint.com/ to check the plugin code so you may avoid at least syntax errors that IE may not like

Answer (score 0):

May be some wrong in your code. see here. remove `<scrip` and try again

```
<scrip  --> What is this?
    </head>
```

Comment: try remove `});` add `})(jQuery);` on the last line in `jquery.template.js`